# JQuery panel hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble getting a simple panel hide script to work. It works for MLAWebsite's panel, but when I click the MLAJournal button nothing happens? I've tried everything I can think of and looked at it for quite a bit now and can't seem to figure it out.

Relevant JQuery and HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //var currentStep = 0;
    
    $("#MLAJournalpanel").hide();
    $("#MLAWebsitepanel").hide();
    
    $("btnMLAJournal").click(function(){
        $("#MLAWebsitepanel").hide();
        $("#MLAJournalpanel").show();
        
        //currentStep = 1;
    });
    
    $("#btnMLAWebsite").click(function(){
        $("#MLAJournalpanel").hide();
        $("#MLAWebsitepanel").show();
        
        //currentStep = 2;
    });
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Code.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
     <style>
     .branding-below {
        bottom: 56px;
        top: 0;
     }

     .branding-text {
        left: 7px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
     }

     .col-contain {
        overflow: hidden;
     }

     .col-one {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
     }

     .logo {
        vertical-align: middle;
     }

     .radio-spacer {
        height: 20px;
     }

     .width-100 {
        width: 100%;
     }
     </style>
     
   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="sidebar branding-below">    
            <input id="btnMLAJournal" type="button" value="MLA Journal"></input>
            <input id="btnMLAWebsite" type="button" value="MLA Website"></input>
            
            <div id="MLAJournalpanel" class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h2>MLA Journal</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="MLAWebsitepanel" class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h1>dadadda</h1>
                    <p>surprise!"</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>      
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a `#` there.

```
$("#btnMLAJournal").click(function(){
    $("#MLAWebsitepanel").hide();
    $("#MLAJournalpanel").show();

    //currentStep = 1;
});
```

Comment: That's the solution of the problem . +1

Answer (score 1):

put `#` on  `$("btnMLAJournal").click(function(){`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //var currentStep = 0;
    
    $("#MLAJournalpanel").hide();
    $("#MLAWebsitepanel").hide();
    
    $("#btnMLAJournal").click(function(){
        $("#MLAWebsitepanel").hide();
        $("#MLAJournalpanel").show();
        
        //currentStep = 1;
    });
    
    $("#btnMLAWebsite").click(function(){
        $("#MLAJournalpanel").hide();
        $("#MLAWebsitepanel").show();
        
        //currentStep = 2;
    });
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Code.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
     <style>
     .branding-below {
        bottom: 56px;
        top: 0;
     }

     .branding-text {
        left: 7px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
     }

     .col-contain {
        overflow: hidden;
     }

     .col-one {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
     }

     .logo {
        vertical-align: middle;
     }

     .radio-spacer {
        height: 20px;
     }

     .width-100 {
        width: 100%;
     }
     </style>
     
   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="sidebar branding-below">    
            <input id="btnMLAJournal" type="button" value="MLA Journal"></input>
            <input id="btnMLAWebsite" type="button" value="MLA Website"></input>
            
            <div id="MLAJournalpanel" class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h2>MLA Journal</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="MLAWebsitepanel" class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h1>dadadda</h1>
                    <p>surprise!"</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>      
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given the id **btnMLAJournal** to your button and calling element from id in jquery requires `#` with id which in your case is missing.
just add `#` to your id in jquery and it will work fine

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    //var currentStep = 0;
    
    $("#MLAJournalpanel").hide();
    $("#MLAWebsitepanel").hide();
    
    //# is added here
    $("#btnMLAJournal").click(function(){
        $("#MLAWebsitepanel").hide();
        $("#MLAJournalpanel").show();
        
        //currentStep = 1;
    });
    
    $("#btnMLAWebsite").click(function(){
        $("#MLAJournalpanel").hide();
        $("#MLAWebsitepanel").show();
        
        //currentStep = 2;
    });
   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
    <base target="_top">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Code.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
     <style>
     .branding-below {
        bottom: 56px;
        top: 0;
     }

     .branding-text {
        left: 7px;
        position: relative;
        top: 3px;
     }

     .col-contain {
        overflow: hidden;
     }

     .col-one {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
     }

     .logo {
        vertical-align: middle;
     }

     .radio-spacer {
        height: 20px;
     }

     .width-100 {
        width: 100%;
     }
     </style>
     
   </head>

   <body>
     <div class="sidebar branding-below">    
            <input id="btnMLAJournal" type="button" value="MLA Journal"></input>
            <input id="btnMLAWebsite" type="button" value="MLA Website"></input>
            
            <div id="MLAJournalpanel" class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h2>MLA Journal</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="MLAWebsitepanel" class="panel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h1>dadadda</h1>
                    <p>surprise!"</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>      
   </body>
</html>
```